# Get order items from a specific product categories in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, orders

How can I get in Woocommerce, only specific order items from a certain product category?

I have searched in Woocommerce docs but I didn't find anything.

Here is my actual code:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {

    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {

        $_product =$order->get_product_from_item( $item );

        ?>

        <a href="<?php echo $_product->get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $_product->get_title() ?></a>
        <br>

        <?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Any Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code too… In the following code, you will define your product category(ies) that can be term Ids, slugs or names (array):

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

// HERE define your product category(ies) in this array (can be term Ids, slugs or names)
$categories = array('clothing')

// Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

if ( sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Just for a defined product category
        if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $item->get_product_id() ) ) {
            // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
            $_product = $item->get_product();
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->get_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $item->get_name() ?></a><br>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Tested and works.

Comment: This helped me in the right direction to modify the code in the way that I needed, thanks so much!